# How to uninstall WildFly 8.2.0.Final on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wildfly, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall WildFly 8.2.0.Final on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server.

The first thing that I do is check if WildFly is running. This is easy task, accessing the url http://serverip:8080.

But the next step is remove completly WildFly 8.2.0.Final to my server.

What is the best way to do this? I want to install the newest version of WildFly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on how it was installed. If it was manually installed, just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have installed it using update-rc.d command run the below two commands

```
update-rc.d wildfly disable
update-rc.d wildfly remove
```

Then delete the symlink wildfly in the /opt folder (or from where ever it was installed).